# Getting rows from this date to this date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

i really couldn't get it.

code-

```
select * 
from Bill_Detail 
where DateTimeofBilling > '8/18/2013 12:00:00 PM' 
  and DateTimeofBilling < '8/20/2013 12:00:00 AM'
```

psudocode-

```
select all 
from Bill_Detail 
where DateTimeofBilling greater than 8/18/2013 
  and DateTimeofBilling less than 8/20/2013
```

i need to get the rows from the date 8/18/2013 to 8/20/2013 but the code returns nothing.

i think this is enough explanation for this . can anyone help?

Comment: are you certain there are rows matching the criteria?

Comment: of course. i got dates within those range but the code return what i expect would be right.

Comment: This codes selects dates from afternoon on 8/18 and whole day on 8/19. Is that the requirement or do you need just 8/19 or included with 8/18 and/or 8/20?

Comment: i would want to get all the rows from between of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
select * from Bill_Detail where DateTimeofBilling > '2013/08/18 12:00:00 PM' and DateTimeofBilling < '2013/08/20 12:00:00 AM'
```

Comment: woa. it worked, but what happened? what did you do? can you explain?

Comment: sql server accept yyyy/mm/dd format so i have convert your date in that format

Comment: you changed the format, i get it. how can you change the format of C#s DateTime.Now to that format, usually DateTime.Now.ToString() would output dateandtime in the format '8/20/2013 12:00:00 PM'

Comment: you can pass format strings to the ToString()-method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: @JeoTalavera if your using this in an application, consider using LINQ instead of sending a query as text.  It may be more natural for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use `PM` (noon, not midnight) for the "greater than" check? Your pseudocode assumes that you also want to use PM.

```
select * 
from Bill_Detail 
where DateTimeofBilling >= '20130818'-- if you want to include this day completely
  and DateTimeofBilling < '20130820' -- if you want to exclude this day completely
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column `DateTimeofBilling` is type datetime, compare it with date and not with varchar:

```
select * 
from Bill_Detail 
where
    DateTimeofBilling >= convert(date, '20130818', 112) and
    DateTimeofBilling < convert(date, '20130821', 112)
```

this one will return you rows with DateTimeofBilling where date is more or equal `2013-08-18` and less or equal `2013-08-20`

Comment: Why not use BETWEEN instead of greaterthan/lessthan?

Comment: If columns are type datetime, you have to carefully choose time of upper bound, so you won't miss any row. I find it more clear to use strictly less and next date

Answer (score 0):

Using between

```
SELECT *
FROM Bill_Detail
WHERE DateTimeofBilling BETWEEN '20130818 000000' 
    AND DateTimeofBilling < '2013/08/20 12:00:00 AM'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select * from Bill_Detail where DateTimeofBilling between '8/18/2013 12:00:00 PM' and  '8/20/2013 12:00:00 AM'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Bill_Detail WHERE DateTimeofBilling>='8/18/2013 12:00:00 PM' AND DateTimeofBilling<='8/20/2013 12:00:00 AM' ORDER BY DateTimeofBilling
```